User management on Azure Cosmos DB MongoDB (vCore)
Regarding Azure CosmosDB with the MongoDB API. I want to stop using RU option (pay per use) in favor of vCore option (pay per capacity).
It is really cheap and specially useful for development environments. I've already deployed an instance and connected an application using the connection string with the adin credentials.
Now I want to add users and roles, but when I try to create a user using 'mongosh' I get always this error when trying to create a user:
db.createUser({ "user":"u1", "pwd":"12345678qwertyui", "roles":[ { "roles":"readWrite", "db":"DEV_ActivityDB"} ]})
MongoServerError[CommandNotSupported]: Command createUser not supported.

In fact, I consistently receive the same error on any user management action:
[mongos] DEV_ActivityDB> db.getUsers()
MongoServerError[CommandNotSupported]: Command usersInfo not supported.

[mongos] DEV_ActivityDB> db.getUser('aUser')
MongoServerError[CommandNotSupported]: Command usersInfo not supported.

It seems vCore option doesn't support creating users like this. Any help on this would be very appreciated.
I'm trying to create a user so applications can connect to cosmos without using admin credentials (which in fact run smoothly).

CosmosDB may not support all the MongoDB commands and features as it is an emulation of MongoDB. You may try this blog to set the user permissions in CosmosDB

It doesn't seems to work with vCore SKU. Maybe it is not yet implemented as pointed by Microsoft here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/answers/questions/1374670/azure-cosmosdb-for-mongodb-vcore-manage-users

@ray i think your comment isn't applicable to vcore
